# How to get Twitter Followers in my ASP.NET MVC3 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-oauth

In my mvc3 application i have used DotNetOpenAuth to authorize twitter user,it works perfect. (user can click on sign in button-> twitter login page will open -> user can pass userid and password-> and login successful)

Now i want to display all followers list.

my code is as follows::=>

Helper-TwitterConsumer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock;
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements;

namespace NerdDinner.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A consumer capable of communicating with Twitter.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TwitterConsumer {
        /// <summary>
        /// The description of Twitter's OAuth protocol URIs for use with actually reading/writing
        /// a user's private Twitter data.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription ServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// The description of Twitter's OAuth protocol URIs for use with their "Sign in with Twitter" feature.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription SignInWithTwitterServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// The URI to get a user's favorites.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint GetFavoritesEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/favorites.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);

        /// <summary>
        /// The URI to get the data on the user's home page.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint GetFollowersEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);

        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint GetFriendTimelineStatusEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);

        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint UpdateProfileBackgroundImageEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/account/update_profile_background_image.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);

        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint UpdateProfileImageEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/account/update_profile_image.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);

        private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint VerifyCredentialsEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);

        private static InMemoryTokenManager ShortTermUserSessionTokenManager {
            get {
                var store = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                var tokenManager = (InMemoryTokenManager)store["TwitterShortTermUserSessionTokenManager"];
                if (tokenManager == null) {
                    string consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"];
                    string consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"];
                    if (IsTwitterConsumerConfigured) {
                        tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
                        store["TwitterShortTermUserSessionTokenManager"] = tokenManager;
                    } else {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No Twitter OAuth consumer key and secret could be found in web.config AppSettings.");
                    }
                }

                return tokenManager;
            }
        }

        private static WebConsumer signInConsumer;

        private static object signInConsumerInitLock = new object();

        private static WebConsumer TwitterSignIn {
            get {
                if (signInConsumer == null) {
                    lock (signInConsumerInitLock) {
                        if (signInConsumer == null) {
                            signInConsumer = new WebConsumer(SignInWithTwitterServiceDescription, ShortTermUserSessionTokenManager);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return signInConsumer;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="TwitterConsumer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        static TwitterConsumer() {
            // Twitter can't handle the Expect 100 Continue HTTP header. 
            ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(GetFavoritesEndpoint.Location).Expect100Continue = false;
        }

        public static bool IsTwitterConsumerConfigured {
            get {
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"]) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"]);
            }
        }


        public static XDocument GetFollowers(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken)
        {
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(GetFavoritesEndpoint, accessToken);
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
        }


        public static XDocument GetUpdates(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken) {
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(GetFriendTimelineStatusEndpoint, accessToken);
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
        }

        public static XDocument GetFavorites(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken) {
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(GetFavoritesEndpoint, accessToken);
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
        }


        public static XDocument UpdateProfileBackgroundImage(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken, string image, bool tile) {
            var parts = new[] {
                MultipartPostPart.CreateFormFilePart("image", image, "image/" + Path.GetExtension(image).Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant()),
                MultipartPostPart.CreateFormPart("tile", tile.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()),
            };
            HttpWebRequest request = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(UpdateProfileBackgroundImageEndpoint, accessToken, parts);
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);
            string responseString = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
            return XDocument.Parse(responseString);
        }

        public static XDocument UpdateProfileImage(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken, string pathToImage) {
            string contentType = "image/" + Path.GetExtension(pathToImage).Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant();
            return UpdateProfileImage(twitter, accessToken, File.OpenRead(pathToImage), contentType);
        }

        public static XDocument UpdateProfileImage(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken, Stream image, string contentType) {
            var parts = new[] {
                MultipartPostPart.CreateFormFilePart("image", "twitterPhoto", contentType, image),
            };
            HttpWebRequest request = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(UpdateProfileImageEndpoint, accessToken, parts);
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.Channel.WebRequestHandler.GetResponse(request);
            string responseString = response.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
            return XDocument.Parse(responseString);
        }

        public static XDocument VerifyCredentials(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken) {
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(VerifyCredentialsEndpoint, accessToken);
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
        }

        public static string GetUsername(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken) {
            XDocument xml = VerifyCredentials(twitter, accessToken);
            XPathNavigator nav = xml.CreateNavigator();
            return nav.SelectSingleNode("/user/screen_name").Value;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Prepares a redirect that will send the user to Twitter to sign in.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="forceNewLogin">if set to <c>true</c> the user will be required to re-enter their Twitter credentials even if already logged in to Twitter.</param>
        /// <returns>The redirect message.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Call <see cref="OutgoingWebResponse.Send"/> or
        /// <c>return StartSignInWithTwitter().<see cref="MessagingUtilities.AsActionResult">AsActionResult()</see></c>
        /// to actually perform the redirect.
        /// </remarks>
        public static OutgoingWebResponse StartSignInWithTwitter(bool forceNewLogin, Uri callback) {
            Contract.Requires(callback != null);

            var redirectParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (forceNewLogin) {
                redirectParameters["force_login"] = "true";
            }

            var request = TwitterSignIn.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, null, redirectParameters);
            return TwitterSignIn.Channel.PrepareResponse(request);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the incoming web request to see if it carries a Twitter authentication response,
        /// and provides the user's Twitter screen name and unique id if available.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="screenName">The user's Twitter screen name.</param>
        /// <param name="userId">The user's Twitter unique user ID.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A value indicating whether Twitter authentication was successful;
        /// otherwise <c>false</c> to indicate that no Twitter response was present.
        /// </returns>
        public static bool TryFinishSignInWithTwitter(out string screenName, out int userId) {
            screenName = null;
            userId = 0;
            var response = TwitterSignIn.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            if (response == null) {
                return false;
            }

            XDocument xml = VerifyCredentials(TwitterSignIn, response.AccessToken);
            XPathNavigator nav = xml.CreateNavigator();
            screenName = nav.SelectSingleNode("/user/screen_name").Value;
            userId = int.Parse(nav.SelectSingleNode("/user/id").Value);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers=>AccountController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using FacebookSolution.Models;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NerdDinner.Helpers;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth;
using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock;

namespace Facebook.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Account/LogOn

        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View();
        }


        private static InMemoryTokenManager _tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager("ksxWgNxWgN8xWgNxWgNWgNg", "H7EfENH7EfEN7H7EfENcr6H4H7EfENNW6AH7EfH7EfENUc");
            private InMemoryTokenManager TokenManager
            {
                get
                {
                    return _tokenManager;
                }
            }
        public ActionResult TwitterOAuth()
        {

            var twitter = new WebConsumer(TwitterConsumer.ServiceDescription,this.TokenManager);

            //Create the URL that we want Twitter to redirect the user to
            var oAuthUrl = new Uri(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Account/OAuth");

            // If we don't yet have access, immediately request it.
            twitter.Channel.Send(twitter.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(oAuthUrl, null, null));

            //This shouldn't happen!!

            return null;
        }

        public ActionResult OAuth()
        {

            var twitter = new WebConsumer(TwitterConsumer.ServiceDescription, this.TokenManager);

            // Process the response
            var accessTokenResponse = twitter.ProcessUserAuthorization();

            // Is Twitter calling back with authorization?
            if (accessTokenResponse != null)
            {

                //Extract the access token & username for use throughout the site
                string accessToken = accessTokenResponse.AccessToken;
                string username = accessTokenResponse.ExtraData["screen_name"];

                CreateAuthCookie(username, accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                //If the request doesn't come with an auth token redirect to the login page
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            //Authentication successful, redirect to the home page
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        private void CreateAuthCookie(string username, string token)
        {
            //Get ASP.NET to create a forms authentication cookie (based on settings in web.config)~
            HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);

            //Decrypt the cookie
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

            //Create a new ticket using the details from the generated cookie, but store the username &
            //token passed in from the authentication method
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
            ticket.IsPersistent, token);

            // Encrypt the ticket & store in the cookie
            cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);

            // Update the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }
        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOn



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

In above code i have written

```
private static readonly MessageReceivingEndpoint GetFollowersEndpoint = new 
MessageReceivingEndpoint("http://twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
```

and

```
public static XDocument GetFollowers(ConsumerBase twitter, string accessToken)
        {
            IncomingWebResponse response = twitter.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(GetFavoritesEndpoint, accessToken);
            return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseReader()));
        }
```

Now what can i do to get list of followers in my view.